# How is Twitter blocking click handlers?

Tags: javascript, onclick, dom-events

I want to add a click handler to a Twitter page which activates globally and preferably supersedes Twitter's many, many click handlers. But I'm finding it impossible to add *any* click handler at all.

Let's take any old Twitter page, say, [this one](https://twitter.com/ietf).

We'll try a couple different things, such as

```
window.addEventListener("click", function(e) { console.log(e); });
// or
document.addEventListener("click", function(e) { console.log(e); });
// or
document.body.addEventListener("click", function(e) { console.log(e); });
```

None of these cause the event to be logged when clicking around the page. Somehow, no matter where I put the event handler and no matter where I click, Twitter beats me to the punch and blocks propagation to my handler. How is it doing this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Discovered shortly before submitting the question:

Twitter isn't blocking the click handlers. It's redefining `console.log` so the messages do not appear. Using `console.error` or a similar function works!